# Jquery issues returning true

Tags: jquery

I am creating a form using AJAX. ON particular conditions I have return false and finally I returned true...

```
$('#addalbum').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

       if(!chk Conditions){
          return false; 

          }
       else
       return true;
   alert("Sankalp after return");
});
```

Though If conditions are going good. But its not returning true condition as my page is not refreshing in case if all conditions are true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have any conditions in the specified code (not to mention that `return true` is commented out and so is useless here anyway), but if you did, then it might look a little something likethis:

```
$('#addalbum').submit(function(e) {
  if (yourCondition) {
    return true;
  }
  e.preventDefault();
  return false;
});
```

What you're doing right now is preventing the default behaviour (which would be to submit the form) regardless of the outcome of anything else.

EDIT per your update and comment:

You are still preventing the default behaviour, essentially discarding the result of anything else - the form won't submit if you `e.preventDefault`, so only do this if your condition isn't met, not first thing.

Comment: @RahulSingh Please take the time to study my answer if you're still unsure: I have edited to reiterate and hopefully clarify.